Running gcloud from a pod in Kubernetes
I have a cronjob that uses a service account to assume an IAM role to auth to GCP account. However, I can't fully use the K8s service account for it for gcloud command.
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: gke-my-service-account@$(GCP_PROJECT_ID).iam.gserviceaccount.com
  name: my-service-account

In Cronjob:
  command:
    - "/bin/sh"
    - "-c"
    - |
      gcloud storage cp $FILE gs://my-gcs-bucket/$FILE

So with this way it fails:
ERROR: (gcloud.storage.cp) You do not currently have an active account selected.
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials.

If you have already logged in with a different account, run:

  $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT

to select an already authenticated account to use.

However if I add, gcloud config set account $GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, it works.
  command:
    - "/bin/sh"
    - "-c"
    - |
      gcloud config set account $GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL
      gcloud storage cp $FILE gs://my-gcs-bucket/$FILE

But I do not want to use the second approach it's just because it worked. Essentially gcloud command should be able to run as the binding service account used in the cronjob can do this auth.
So what's wrong with this? How can I use gcloud cli without gcloud config manually? I can run AWS cli with a service account annotation and it doesn't require any configuration manually. So I believe there should be a way to do in GCP too.
Thank you for your help in advance!

I temporarily resolved the issue by setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable as shown below:
env:
  - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
    value: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

However, I still feel this shouldn't be necessary since AWS doesn't require any such configuration.

Based on what you are trying to do,I believe using Workload Identity is better option approach for GKE in Google Cloud to handle service account authentication seamlessly, without needing to set environment variables like GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS manually. Here’s a detailed breakdown of how to set it up for your use case:

Enable Workload Identity on Your GKE Cluster
Make sure that Workload Identity is enabled on your GKE cluster. You can enable it when creating a new cluster with the following flag:


gcloud container clusters create [CLUSTER_NAME] \
    --workload-pool=[PROJECT_ID].svc.id.goog


Or, if your cluster is already created, update it to enable Workload Identity:

gcloud container clusters update [CLUSTER_NAME] 
--workload-pool=[PROJECT_ID].svc.id.goog


Create and Annotate the Kubernetes Service Account
Define your Kubernetes Service Account (KSA) and link it to a Google Service Account (GSA) using an annotation. Ensure the Google Service Account has the necessary IAM roles for accessing the resources.


apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: my-service-account
  namespace: [NAMESPACE]
  annotations:
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: gke-my-service-account@[PROJECT_ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com



Grant IAM Policy Binding
Grant the GSA permission to impersonate the KSA. This allows the workload running in the Kubernetes pod to assume the identity of the GSA automatically.


gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
    gke-my-service-account@[PROJECT_ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
    --member "serviceAccount:[PROJECT_ID].svc.id.goog[[NAMESPACE]/my-service-account]"



Update the CronJob to Use the Service Account
In your CronJob definition, specify serviceAccountName: my-service-account to use the KSA.


apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-cronjob
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: my-service-account
          containers:
          - name: my-container
            image: gcr.io/[PROJECT_ID]/[IMAGE_NAME]
            command:
              - "/bin/sh"
              - "-c"
              - |
                gcloud storage cp $FILE gs://my-gcs-bucket/$FILE



Verifying Automatic Authentication
With Workload Identity set up, you shouldn’t need to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable manually. The gcloud CLI in your container should recognize the linked service account without additional configurations, as it leverages the Kubernetes service account’s annotation to impersonate the Google Service Account.

Additional Notes
If you’re still encountering issues with the active account, ensure that your container image has the latest gcloud SDK, as there have been updates to better support Workload Identity.
If you're trying this outside GCP's default setup, you may still need to fall back on the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS workaround, but in most cases, Workload Identity handles the impersonation seamlessly, like AWS IAM roles.
